# Removing duplicate characters from a list in Python where the pattern repeats

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am monitoring a serial port that sends data that looks like this:

```py
['','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',
 '','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d',
 '','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a',
 '','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c',
 '','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e',
 '','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',
 '','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d',
 '','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a',
 '','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c',
 '','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','']
```

I need to be able to convert this into:

```py
['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']
```

So I'm removing duplicates and empty strings, but also retaining the number of times the pattern repeats itself.

I haven't been able to figure it out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a list comprehension and [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest): keep an element only if it's not an empty string, and not equal to the next element. You can use an iterator to skip the first element, to avoid the cost of slicing the list.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def remove_consecutive_duplicates(lst):
    ahead = iter(lst)
    next(ahead)
    return [ x for x, y in zip_longest(lst, ahead) if x and x != y ]
```

Usage:

```py
>>> remove_consecutive_duplicates([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2])
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2]
>>> remove_consecutive_duplicates(my_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I'm assuming either that there are no duplicates separated by empty strings (e.g. `'a', '', 'a'`), or that you don't want to remove such duplicates. If this assumption is wrong, then you should filter out the empty strings first:

```py
>>> example = ['a', '', 'a']
>>> remove_consecutive_duplicates([ x for x in example if x ])
['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list and add the appropriate contitions. For the response that you are expecting, you just need to whether previous character is not same as current character

```
    current_sequence = ['','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','']

sequence_list = []
for x in range(len(current_sequence)):
    if current_sequence[x]:
        if current_sequence[x] != current_sequence[x-1]:
            sequence_list.append(current_sequence[x])

print(sequence_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that

```
li = ['','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','']

new_li = []
e_ = ''

for e in li:
    if len(e) > 0 and e_ != e:
        new_li.append(e)
        e_ = e

print(new_li)
```

Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

if your list is `ll`

```
ll = [i for i in ll if i]
out = []
for k, g in groupby(ll, key=lambda x: ord(x)):
    out.append(chr(k))
print(out)
#prints ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
# data <- your data
a = [k for k, v in groupby(data) if k] # approach 1
b = list(filter(bool, map(itemgetter(0), groupby(data)))) # approach 2
assert a == b
print(a)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `set` method you can remove the duplicates from the list

```
data = ['','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',
 '','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d',
 '','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a',
 '','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c',
 '','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e',
 '','','a','a','a','a','a','a','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',
 '','','c','c','c','c','c','c','','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d',
 '','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','','a','a','a','a','a','a',
 '','','','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','','','c','c','c','c','c','c',
 '','','','d','d','d','d','d','d','','','e','e','e','e','e','e','','']

print(set(data))
```